# What is a term for recent that covers the past week and the next week?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests

I have a software user interface that toggles between the full schedule and a schedule that covers the most recent weekend and the upcoming weekend. Any idea what to call this?

Comment: I don't believe there is a common English term for this.

Comment: The people who will use your software must have a particular need to see this not-quite-a-week schedule, or you wouldn't be building it. So ... what do they call it? Either in person, or in their existing system. What does it do for them? See also: *'There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things. -- Phil Karlton'* - http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html

Comment: @Phil Nice! I'm a software developer and I've run into both of these issues today.

Comment: @Phil Great point, but there is no term I'm aware of. I'm adding the feature because I think that's the only part of the schedule that people care about 80% of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for something that's reasonably self-explanatory, like "weekend-weekend" or, if space is limited, an appropriate abbreviation. If you have to abbreviate it, make sure you have a tooltip that expands the abbreviation.

Comment: weekend-weekend is a great suggestion that I would not have come up with on my own.